# After decode utf-8 I get TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Tags: python, json, utf-8

I get below error even after using decode('utf-8').

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

Now I've read that quite few people faced similar problem in 3.x, but most of them solve it by using decode function, which doesn't seem to work for me. Can anyone give me a hand on this? I'm very beginner in Python.

```
import urllib.request
import json

request = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/56els'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
obj = json.load(response)
str_response = response.readall().decode('utf-8')

print(obj)
```

Comment: The two lines that use `response` are independent of each other; which one raises the error? You probably just want to assign the return value of `response.json()` to something, replacing one or both the current lines.

Comment: `obj = json.load(response)` is using the error. I also noticed I put print obj and not str_response which is decoded, but it did not help with the error.  I tried your way, but perhaps i am doing something not right

Answer (score 0):

You're close - you need to put the decode before the `json.load`. I.e.

```
import urllib.request
import json

request = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/56els'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
str_response = response.readall().decode('utf-8')
obj = json.load(str_response)

print(obj)
```

Your code assumes the webserver is returning "utf-8" encoding data. You should inspect the `Content-type` header on the response and set the decode appropriately. Alternatively, use the `Requests` library which has automatic decoding builtin. It also decodes to JSON, which will should help you further.

Comment: many thanks! I also found that I can read it with pandas too `data = pd.read_json('https://api.myjson.com/bins/33g8e')`. I plan to utilize them later on.
edit: I tried to run code but I got attribute error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'`